# How to compare strings in perl?

Tags: perl, selenium-rc

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Time::HiRes qw(sleep);
use Test::WWW::Selenium;
use Test::More "no_plan";
use Test::Exception;
use Text::Table; 
our ($a,$critical);

print "Enter text:";
$a = <>;
print "Enter critical value:";
$critical = <>;
print $a;
print $critical;
|
|
|
|
|
$sel->click_ok("//div[\@class='x-combo-list-inner']/div[8]");
my $v7 = $sel->get_text("//div[\@class='x-combo-list-inner']/div[8]");
print($v7 . "\n");
print($critical . "\n");
if ($critical eq $v7)
{
perform operations
}
else
{
don't perform operation
}
```

The value of the critical which i enter from cmd i `'Last 45 Days'`  & the value retrieved from div[8] & stored in v7 in the above code is also same `('Last 45 Days')`. But when it encounters the if loop, it doesn't perform the operation. Is there any other ways to compare these kind of strings ?

Comment: Try dumping the octets from each string to see if there's something invisibly different (different kinds of white space, etc.)  Use `ord`, for example.  If something as simple as `eq` isn't doing what you expect, you have to ask the question, "Well, what *is* different about these two strings?"

Comment: Show the output of `use Devel::Peek; Dump $critical; Dump $v7`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably have a newline appended on $critical. Try removing it with chomp($critical);

Comment: When i print the value of v7 & critical, both prints the same value Last 45 Days. Is there any other way to do this ?

Comment: @Jackie James:  A trailing newline will be invisible in your output. You *should* `chomp` the input from the keyboard anyway as it *will* contain a newline and isn't part of the data you're interested in.

Comment: @ Kludas & Borodin : Thank u very much. I've used chomp to remove the newline character.

Answer (score 0):

As Kludas says is is more than likely that you have a newline at the end of `$critical`. You certainly show no code that removes it, and the string returned by `get_text` is unlikely to end in a newline.

I suggest you use [`Data::Dump`](https://metacpan.org/module/Data%3a%3aDump) (note *NOT* `Data::Dumper`) to display your strings. Once you have installed the module it is simply a matter of

```
use Data::Dump;

dd $critical;
dd $v7;
```

and any non-printables will be shown as the appropriate visible escape code.